# how to get a while loop in my rock paper scissors program to work?

Tags: python

i wrote this code for a rock paper scissors game and added the last three lines as to restart the playthrough, but it only ends the program. someone please tell me how to code this so where the loop would work correctly.

when it asks 'play again? y/n' and you'd answer 'yes', it only ends the program.

```
from random import randint

#create a list of options
c = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

#assign a random play to the computer
computer = c[randint(0,2)]

#set player to False
player = True

while player == True:

     player = input('Rock, Paper, or Scissors?')
     if player == computer:
        print('Tie!')
     elif player == 'Rock':
        if computer == 'Paper':
            print('You lose!', computer, 'covers', player) 
        else: 
            print('You win!', player, 'smashes', computer)  
     elif player == 'Paper':
        if computer == 'Scissors':
            print('You lose', computer, 'cuts', player)
        else: 
            print('You win!', player, 'covers', computer) 
     elif player == 'Scissors':
        if computer == 'Rock':
            print('You lose!', computer, 'smashes', player)  
        else:
            print('You win!', player, 'cuts', computer) 
     else:
        print('Not a valid answer. Please try again.')

     play_again = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
     if play_again.lower() != "y":
        break
```

Comment: As a general rule, don't ever write `x == True` or `x == False`.  Use Python's truthiness feature, and just write `x` or `not x`.

Comment: The program will be terminated when you answer "yes" because `"y"!="yes"`, and therefore the `break` will be executed.

Answer (score 4):

*player* is initially bool but you then assign str (via *input()*).

Therefore, on the second iteration of the loop the condition *player == True* will be False.

You could just write:

```
while True:
```

...because you terminate the loop with *break*

Answer (score 0):

As Codist said it is enough to just use `while True:`.

You can also use regex for the repetition.

```
while True:
...

   import re

   otp = input('Play again? y/n, yes/no: ')
   if not re.match('^[yes|y]$', otp.lower()): 
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use a little more refactoring but I made a few changes:
First, I chose to import the `choice` function from the `random` module instead of using `randint` as you did. Also instead of always asking players repeatedly if they want to play again, why not just ask it at the same time they are entering their choice? If they enter 'q', the program quits. This eliminates the need for the last three lines in your program. Finally, as Codist mentioned, just use `while True`. See the refactored version here:

```
from random import choice

#create a list of options
c = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

#assign a random play to the computer
computer = choice(c)

while True:
     player = input('Enter a choice (Rock, Paper, or Scissors) or enter q to quit: ')
     if player == 'q':
         break
     if player == computer:
        print('Tie!')
     elif player == 'Rock':
        if computer == 'Paper':
            print('You lose!', computer, 'covers', player) 
        else: 
            print('You win!', player, 'smashes', computer)  
     elif player == 'Paper':
        if computer == 'Scissors':
            print('You lose', computer, 'cuts', player)
        else: 
            print('You win!', player, 'covers', computer) 
     elif player == 'Scissors':
        if computer == 'Rock':
            print('You lose!', computer, 'smashes', player)  
        else:
            print('You win!', player, 'cuts', computer) 
     else:
        print('Not a valid answer. Please try again.')
```